# Xamarin Forms IOS open PDF

Tags: c#, ios, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to open pdf file from file system.
I know how to get path to the file, but my IPhone does not open it.

I use the following code renderer:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using IdokladX.Services;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IdokladX.iOS.Services.PdfViewer))]
namespace IdokladX.iOS.Services {
public class PdfViewer:IPdfViewer {

    public void OpenPdf(string filename)
    {
        FileWorker fl = new FileWorker();

        if (fl.Exists(filename))
        {
            string strPfad = fl.GetFilePath(filename);

            var viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(strPfad));
            var controller = GetVisibleViewController();
            viewer.PresentOpenInMenu(controller.View.Frame, controller.View, true);
        }
    }
    private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController(UIViewController controller = null)
    {
        controller = controller ?? UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

        if (controller.PresentedViewController == null)
            return controller;

        if (controller.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
        {
            return ((UINavigationController)controller.PresentedViewController).VisibleViewController;
        }

        if (controller.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
        {
            return ((UITabBarController)controller.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
        }

        return GetVisibleViewController(controller.PresentedViewController);
    }
    }
}
```

Here `FileWorker` is a class which contains methods to save/delete/check file if it exists.
What is wrong? I have also added the file type PDF in my Info.plist file.

[image]

What is wrong ? Don't advice me to use WebView, I need to open pdf file via another program.

Comment: Do you mean there's no popup when you trigger  `PresentOpenInMenu()`?
 Do you have any other app can open the pdf file?

Comment: You can test it on your device which has installed some other pdf viewer apps.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for advice! Sure, I don't have any pdf viewer app on my simulator6 but I have safari... I guess it should open it, am I wrong?

Comment: I test it on my side, safari can't do it. But iBooks and Notes can open pdf. So, use a device which has such apps to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reference:**

See the documentation for [presentOpenInMenu(from:in:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/1616807-presentopeninmenu):

> If there are no registered apps that support opening the document, the document interaction controller does not display a menu.

**Solution:**

Test the "Open in ..." on your **device** and **make sure there's some app can open the pdf file (such as iBooks, Notes, Chrome and so on)**. Otherwise, the menu will not show.

**Notice：**

You don't need add the `Document Type` for PDF, if you just need other apps to open your file. `Document Type` is used to show your app in the "Open in ..." menu to open other apps' file when some other apps trigger `presentOpenInMenu`.

Comment: @ManOfWar, if my answer is helpful, can you accept it? It is important to me! Thanks!